# Nsight Eclipse Edition 7.5 add compile command to link library

Tags: cuda, nvcc, nsight

I would like to link the `cusparse` library using `-lcusparse` for the nvcc complier in Nsight, i.e. something like this
`nvcc test_sparse.cu -lcusparse -o test_CUSPARSE`.

Where exactly can I add this in Nsight 7.5, I only found explanations for older versions.

Answer (score 2):

You could find it here if you are not using makefile project.

Project Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Linker -> Libraries

Comment: I imported an existing project into workspace, nevertheless I can not find the settings you recommended. Is there maybe a way to include it in the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: @SemtexB "if you are not using makefile project"